# with expo after Web Bundling complete , showing blank page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, webpack, expo

i followed a tutorial for adding web support using to a expo project **. using **typescript, react-native-web** and **webpack**. looks like it works for everyone. but for me, i get a blank web page after **Web Bundling complete**.

> Started Metro Bundler
> Web Bundling complete

even though it works just fine on the emulator. i get no error in the console.

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "imibonano",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d web-build",
    "predeploy": "expo build:web",
    "commit": "node scripts/github.js"

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/poppins": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.16.24",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.2.3",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "dotenv": "^14.2.0",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "^5.4.8",
    "expo-font": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^8.1.7",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "~0.9.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.4",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-custom-swiper": "^1.0.16",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.146.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": " ~2.2.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.15",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^3.0.16",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-native-web-swiper": "^2.2.2",
    "react-query": "^3.39.1",
    "react-query-native-devtools": "^4.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.66.13",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "private": true
}
```

`app.tsx`:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";

import NavigationStack from "./navigation/NavigationStack";
import Providers from "./navigation/index";
import useCachedResources from './hooks/useCachedResources';
import useColorScheme from './hooks/useColorScheme';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import { AuthProvider } from "./navigation/AuthProvider";
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import AppNavigation from './navigation';

import {
  useFonts,
  // Poppins_100Thin,
  // Poppins_100Thin_Italic,
  // Poppins_200ExtraLight,
  // Poppins_200ExtraLight_Italic,
  // Poppins_300Light,
  // Poppins_300Light_Italic,
  Poppins_400Regular,
  // Poppins_400Regular_Italic,
  Poppins_500Medium,
  // Poppins_500Medium_Italic,
  Poppins_600SemiBold,
  // Poppins_600SemiBold_Italic,
  // Poppins_700Bold,
  // Poppins_700Bold_Italic,
  // Poppins_800ExtraBold,
  // Poppins_800ExtraBold_Italic,
  // Poppins_900Black,
  // Poppins_900Black_Italic 
} from '@expo-google-fonts/poppins';

export default function App() {

  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    title: require('./assets/fonts/klarissa.regular.ttf'),
    Poppins_400Regular,
    Poppins_600SemiBold,
    Poppins_500Medium
  });


  if (!isLoadingComplete || !loaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return <Providers />;

  }
}

  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#0a0a0a",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
}
})
```

`index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import { AuthProvider } from "./AuthProvider";
import NavigationStack from "./NavigationStack";


export default function Providers() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <NavigationStack />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```